# Rapidminer studio and java 8

Tags: java, java-8, rapidminer

I have this simple code, which works in RapidMiner 5 with Java 6, and also works with RapidMiner Studio with Java 7. The problem is with Java 8, it displays an error that the requested repository doesn't exist!

```
public void LoadDataProcess(String Data, ArrayList <Data> DataArray, ArrayList<String> Labels, ArrayList<String> AttributIndex)throws MalformedRepositoryLocationException{
    try {
    // loads the process from the repository
    RepositoryLocation loc = new RepositoryLocation("//Repository/MyData/"+ Data);
    IOObjectEntry entry = (IOObjectEntry) loc.locateEntry();
    IOObject myIOObject= entry.retrieveData(null);
    IOContainer ioInput = new IOContainer(new IOObject[] {myIOObject});
    ExampleSet resultSet = ioInput.get(ExampleSet.class);
    //Recuperatr attributs
}
```

The error is:

```
com.rapidminer.repository.RepositoryException: Requested repository Repository does not exist.
at com.rapidminer.repository.RepositoryManager.getRepository(RepositoryManager.java:192)
at com.rapidminer.repository.RepositoryLocation.getRepository(RepositoryLocation.java:161)
at com.rapidminer.repository.RepositoryLocation.locateEntry(RepositoryLocation.java:187)
```

What is the problem with Java 8?  I must work with Java 8 and RapidMiner.

Comment: I don't know anything about RapidMiner, but [this thread](http://rapid-i.com/rapidforum/index.php?topic=8571.0) indicates that it doesn't work well at all with Java 8.

Comment: @FiveNine are you sure the path you giving to Repository is correct?